Using Uuids alongside PK in database
In my database, tables have both a sequential id primary key generated by postgres (i.e 1,2,3...)
and also a db generated uuidV4 which i've name as public_id. The purpose of the public_id is to prevent having to expose the sequential id to the frontend and creating url routes from that (i.e /products/1234)
I've read mixed arguments for both not exposing and exposing sequential id's as well as having uuids alongside in the db
the problem i face is that since i'm only sending the public_id to the client, i have to always make an extra query against my join tables for my many to many relations since these reference the sequential id. (i.e get PK id using the UUID field and in order to get the relations in my join table)
how expensive is it to always have to do this extra step to get the PK? vs just exposing my PK to the client and hashing it for example. or is it fine the way it is... alternatively, i was thinking to send both ID's to the client only exposing the uuid in the url and then using the PK solely for data fetching against my API

I don't see the problem you are solving, /products/1234 means you want people to find your products. What does it matter that they may deduce there is a /products/1235 also? It is what you allow them to do after they get to a product page that counts.

You do not need an extra step. Do your joins and use the uuid in the where clause
